# How do I convert a Quantum Circuit into a qobj

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-circuit

I have a Quantum Circuit launched but I want to convert it into a qobj to use the function .run from qiskit, I've tried to use the function:

```
qobj = assemble(QuantumCircuit)
```

but it returns

```
'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'config'
```

and I've failed to find the "config" needed on the qiskit instructions.
Does anyone know's how do I convert it properly and fill's this configurations?

Here is a print of the qobj after assemble:

```
QASM Qobj: 3d6e9e20-290e-4c7d-a2e7-c0b5a8e38f2e:
Config: {'init_qubits': True,
 'memory': False,
 'memory_slots': 3,
 'n_qubits': 3,
 'parameter_binds': [],
 'shots': 1024}
Header: {}
Experiments:

QASM Experiment:
Header:
{'clbit_labels': [['c', 0], ['c', 1], ['c', 2]],
 'creg_sizes': [['c', 3]],
 'global_phase': 0.0,
 'memory_slots': 3,
 'n_qubits': 3,
 'name': 'circuit',
 'qreg_sizes': [['q', 3]],
 'qubit_labels': [['q', 0], ['q', 1], ['q', 2]]}
Config:
{'memory_slots': 3, 'n_qubits': 3}

    Instruction: ry
        params: [1.0]
        qubits: [0]

    Instruction: rz
        params: [2.0]
        qubits: [0]

    Instruction: h
        qubits: [0]

    Instruction: measure
        qubits: [0]
        memory: [0]

    Instruction: ry
        params: [1.0]
        qubits: [2]

    Instruction: rz
        params: [2.0]
        qubits: [2]

    Instruction: measure
        qubits: [2]
        memory: [2]

    Instruction: ry
        params: [1.0]
        qubits: [1]

    Instruction: rz
        params: [2.0]
        qubits: [1]

    Instruction: sdg
        qubits: [1]

    Instruction: h
        qubits: [1]

    Instruction: measure
        qubits: [1]
        memory: [1]
```

it still's return the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The function `assemble` takes a `QuantumCircuit` instance, not the type:

```
qobj = assemble(QuantumCircuit())
type(qobj)
```

```
qiskit.qobj.qasm_qobj.QasmQobj
```

For example:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)

qobj = assemble(circuit)
print(qobj)
```

```
QASM Qobj: 2a18a692-be49-452e-8631-72865c890d05:
Config: {'init_qubits': True,
...
...
    Instruction: h
        qubits: [0]

    Instruction: cx
        qubits: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Yes I already have a 3 qubit 3 cr Quantum Circuit instance launched on my code, but when I try to use assemble on it, it returns the error that I said.

Comment: I dont get it, sorry. `assemble` raise the error but creates the qobj anyway? Maybe share a minimal failing example...